# Why doesn't ldapsearch over ssl/tls work?

Tags: ldap, starttls

I am trying to use ldapsearch over a SSL/TLS connection, but it doesn't work:

```
ldapsearch -ZZ -d 5 -b "cn=Users,dc=my,dc=server,dc=com" -s sub -D
"cn=mydevice,cn=Users,dc=my,dc=server,dc=com" -h my.server.com -p 3269
-w "mypass" -x "(cn=test)"

ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://my.server.com:3269)
ldap_extended_operation_s
ldap_extended_operation
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP my.server.com:3269
ldap_new_socket: 3
ldap_prepare_socket: 3
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 10.199.46.70:3269
ldap_connect_timeout: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
ldap_open_defconn: successful
ldap_send_server_request
ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
ber_scanf fmt ({) ber:
ber_flush: 31 bytes to sd 3
ldap_result ld 0x95ff590 msgid 1
wait4msg ld 0x95ff590 msgid 1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x95ff590 msgid 1 all 1
** ld 0x95ff590 Connections:
* host: my.server.com  port: 3269  (default)
refcnt: 2  status: Connected
last used: Mon Feb 27 10:59:43 2012

** ld 0x95ff590 Outstanding Requests:
* msgid 1,  origid 1, status InProgress
outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
** ld 0x95ff590 Response Queue:
Empty
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x95ff590 msgid 1 all 1
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x95ff590 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x95ff590 msgid 1 all 1
ber_get_next
ldap_perror
ldap_start_tls: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

The error message doesn't give enough of a hint on what is wrong. In contrast, a simple binding and search goes well without any problem on port 389.

Any hint?

P.S. Here is my ldap.conf:

```
TLS_REQCERT demand
TLS_CACERT ./cacert.pem
```

I have even tried to change `TLS_REQCERT` to `never`, but it still doesn't work. :-(

Comment: It doesn't look like its attempting to use TLS. You could use the -H switch instead, with an LDAP URL:

ldapsearch -ZZ -d 5 -b "cn=Users,dc=my,dc=server,dc=com" -s sub -D "cn=mydevice,cn=Users,dc=my,dc=server,dc=com" -H ldaps://my.server.com:3269 -w "mypass" -x "(cn=test)"

Comment: You may want to add a per-user .ldaprc file with the above and use full path for TLS_CACERT. Also see TLS_CACERTDIR and manpage of ldap.conf.

Answer (score 74):

First, replace `-h my.server.com -p 3269` with `-H ldaps://my.server.com:3269` as suggested by @dearlbry.

Then, in `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf` (or `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` on my Ubuntu 13.04), disable certificate verification by adding this :

```
HOST my.server.com
PORT 3269
TLS_REQCERT ALLOW
```

You can also create a `ldaprc` file in the current directory with the same content if you don't want to affect the whole system.

This will enable ldapsearch over SSL, but without verification. Follow these [steps to add certificate validation](https://forums.opensuse.org/t/performing-ldapsearch-over-tls-ssl-against-active-directory/15075/2)(URL updated 2023) to the mix.

Comment: Note you can do this temporarily via an environment variable `LDAPTLS_REQCERT=ALLOW`  (also `LDAPTLD_CERT=/path/to/cert` and so on but I couldn't get that to work because it asks for a keyfile that I don't have).

Comment: OP hss TLS_CACERT set - which should be all he needs although he should probably use a user-config ($HOME/.ldaprc) and a full path for TLS_CACERT.