# OpenLDAP - TDS - Can't contact LDAP server (-1)

Tags: ssl, ldap, tds

i want to try to connect to a TDS - Server via ldapsearch. First I have downloaded "OpenLDAP" but now with the command:

```
ldapsearch -H ldaps://myhostadress:636
```

i always get the following error:

```
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Can't contact LDAP serv
additional info: error:14090086:SSL routines:
:certificate verify failed (self signed certificate)
```

I attached to my command "-d1" for more information and got:

```
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://xxx:636)
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://xxxx:636/??base)
ldap_pvt_sasl_getmech
ldap_search
put_filter: "(objectclass=*)"
put_filter: simple
put_simple_filter: "objectclass=*"
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP xxxxx:636
ldap_new_socket: 360
ldap_prepare_socket: 360
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 9.xxxxxx:636
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 360 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect:
connect success
TLS trace: SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
TLS certificate verification: depth: 0, err: 18, subject: /O=org/OU=OrgUnit
Germany/CN=xxxxx, issuer: /O=org/OU=OrgUnit
Germany/CN=xxxx
TLS certificate verification: Error, self signed certificate
TLS trace: SSL3 alert write:fatal:unknown CA
TLS trace: SSL_connect:error in error
TLS trace: SSL_connect:error in error
TLS: can't connect: error:14090086:SSL
routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed (self signed certificate).
ldap_msgfree
ldap_err2string
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
    additional info: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed (self signed certificate)
```

I think that has something to do with the ssl-certificate!? I have read some other threads with similar problems. 
After that i have asked my administrator for the ssl certificate and got a .pem file with following structure (it's just an extract):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----
mcdp+Kh5Zd3YOttXbjemxIvwfRvPd/Ho4VtBsi5yJT5DSehL4L8ZN
DKaSL6BQ5MlQ1bsmQQ04PKNBrPKFFIiadi9QsFrUiNCQSKDLSKDSK
XbjemxIvwfRvPd/Ho4VtBsi5yJT5DSehL4L8ZNIUWEISNSDJKLSDJ
DKaUiNCXbjemxIvwfRvPdHo4VtBsi5yJT5DSSDKOSOÖDKJLSDJKSD
hL4L8ZNL6BQ5MlQ1bsmQQ04PKNBrPKFFIiadi9QsFrUiNCJKLSADN
.....................................................
.....................................................
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

What do i have to do now? The OpenLDAP folder for the certifcates is

```
`C:\OpenLDAP-2.4.43\etc\certs
```

and the config file in ,

```
`C:\OpenLDAP-2.4.43\etc\openldap`
```

I have tried as explained in [Performing ldapsearch over TLS/SSL against Active Directory](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/401522-performing-ldapsearch-over-tls-ssl-against-active-directory#post1908811) and added to my ldap.conf

```
HOST hostxyz.com
PORT 636
TLS_CACERT \etc\certs\trustKey.cer     //  C:\OpenLDAP-2.4.43\etc\cert\trustKey.cer   ; .pem file changed into .cer file
TLS_REQCERT demand
```

and start the call with `ldapmodify -H ldaps://hostxyz.com:636`
But i always get the error mentioned.

Best Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ldapsearch over ssl/tls doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468137/ldapsearch-over-ssl-tls-doesnt-work)

Comment: I have tried to adjust it, but it still doesn't work, so i have updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

This work for me!

Add this to the file /etc/openldap/ldap.conf

```
TLS_REQCERT allow
```

Then restart the LDAP

```
systemctl restart slapd
systemctl enable slapd
```