# Connecting via TLS to OPENLDAP: Certificate not found

Tags: docker, ssl, ldap, tls1.2, openldap

I have an OpenLDAP Docker instance from [Osixia](https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap) and am trying to query it securely from the client using TLS. The query works without encryption using `$ ldapwhoami -H ldap://localhost -x` and does not work when using the `-ZZ` flag to start TLS operation `$ ldapwhoami -H ldap://localhost -x -ZZ`    - it returns `ldap_start_tls: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)`. How can i make this work? Below are all the steps i took:

1. Run LDAP server in docker:

```sh
$ docker run -p 389:389 -p 636:636 --name ldap-service --hostname ldap-service \
--env LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD="password" --env LDAP_BASE_DN="dc=example,dc=org" --detach  osixia/openldap:1.4.0
```

2. Test Connectivity - shows success, it returns `anonymous`

```sh
$ ldapwhoami -H ldap://localhost -x
anonymous
```

3. Preparations for TLS  connectivity - Configure client to trust SERVER Certificate Authority (CA)

   1. SERVER DOCKER CONTAINER: TLS certs are autoconfigured upon runtime in the osixia/openldap image. Copy contents of CA in `/container/service/slapd/assets/certs/ca.crt`
   2. CLIENT:  Paste the copied SERVER `ca.crt` into CLIENT folder `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt` , then run `sudo update-ca-certificates` to add it. Confirm success of adding by checking that the CA is inside `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`
   3. CLIENT: In file`/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` I added the line `TLS_CACERT      /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`
4. Test TLS connectivity from CLIENT via `-ZZ` flag to start TLS operation:

```sh
$ ldapwhoami -H ldap://localhost -x -ZZ   
ldap_start_tls: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
        additional info: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
```

Further logs from inside LDAP docker:

```sh
5ff42195 conn=1079 fd=12 ACCEPT from IP=172.17.0.1:39420 (IP=0.0.0.0:636)
TLS: can't accept: No certificate was found..
5ff42195 conn=1079 fd=12 closed (TLS negotiation failure)
```

5. Test TLS connectivity from CLIENT via LDAP Secure URI scheme `ldaps://`

```sh
$ ldapwhoami -H ldaps://localhost -x 
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

Things i tried out:

- I read through https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/tls.html and subsequently installed the Server CA on the client.
- I read through this post: [ldapsearch over ssl/tls doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468137/ldapsearch-over-ssl-tls-doesnt-work), I changed the settings in `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` to include the below items, but to no avail.

```sh
 TLS_CACERT      /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
 TLS_REQCERT ALLOW
 PORT 636
 HOST localhost // i also tried 'ldap-service'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

Add `--env LDAP_TLS_VERIFY_CLIENT=try` to the `docker run` command. [Source](https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap/issues/105#issuecomment-279673189)

Answer (score 1):

For Googlers,

Presto does not supply client certificates (client certificate verification, two-way verification) when connecting to LDAP service, so you will need `--env LDAP_TLS_VERIFY_CLIENT=try`or `never` if you use `osixia/openldap`, or, edit `ldap.conf` and set `TLS_REQCERT never` and restart the LDAP service.